# Are ultrasonic sensors good for obstacle detection?

Tags: long-range-drone, ultrasonic-sensor

I am trying to fit front looking ultrasonic sensor for object detection in my small drone. It will be an outdoor drone and I want to build a reliable system to detect objects and avoid collision. How good are ultrasonic sensors for that? How can I compare camera based object depth detection vs ultrasonic depth detection?

Comment: [This small LiDAR](https://www.adafruit.com/product/4058?gclid=Cj0KCQjw1ZeUBhDyARIsAOzAqQIM8KESOe7mYIJs7yFEEA9MkiXvkregTrs-Ml71gak5ffvxMnga1a8aAjLeEALw_wcB) has an effective range of 40 meters and might suit your need well.

Answer (score 3):

Ultrasonic detectors are frequently used for obstacle detection on wheeled robots, where a range of 2 or 3 meters is adequate. For a drone, that might not be enough warning - especially for difficult targets like a thin branch or overhead wire.

I think there are longer range ultrasonic detectors (up to 5 or 10m), but they are larger, heavier and user more power.

Comment: Unless you're talking about hobbyist drones (DJI Tello), or other chinese variants which may use them to auto-land or follow your hand around.